# Export errors while exporting CSS using Webpack v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, css-loader

```
WARNING in ./src/components/desktop/layout/AutoAuth.js 48:12-21
export 'layerHide' (imported as 'layerHide') was not found in '../../../css/layout.css' (possible exports: default)
@ ./src/components/desktop/pages/LoadUser.js 4:0-42 6:42-50
@ ./src/router.js 60:0-59 119:15-23
@ ./src/index.js 8:0-30 31:83-89
```

I am getting this warning for every file that is importing CSS. I recently was in the process of updating to Webpack v5.

This is how it is imported in every file:

```
import {layerShow, layerHide, siteWrapper} from "../../../css/layout.css";
```

Relevant block in the webpack.config.js file:

```
      {
        test: /\.(sa|sc|c)ss$/i,
        use: [
          { loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader },
          {
            loader: "css-loader",
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: "[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
              }
            }
          },
          "postcss-loader",
          'sass-loader',
        ]
      },
```

Versions of the modules:

```
sass-loader: 14.1.0
postcss-loader: 8.1.0
css-loader: 6.10.0
mini-css-extract-plugin: 2.8.0
webpack: 5.90.1
```

Any help is appreciated, I've been trying to fix this for hours.

I have tried changing the directory of the CSS files, using an alias, trying different combinations of options for css-loader in webpack.config.js. I did not have this problem before updating.

Comment: It seems unlikely given that it's CSS, but do you have any dependency cycles between these files? Eg A imports B, B imports C, C imports A.

Comment: I don't know if I have a way to check that as this is from a very big code base.

Comment: Look into `circular-dependency-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the option `namedExport: true` of `css-loader` yet?

On the other hand, if you're trying to use CSS Modules then you have to name your CSS files with postfix `.module.css`.

Comment: I have and it had not solved the problem. I solved it by changing the way CSS is imported for every file.

Comment: @Ivl You need to name your CSS files as `.module.css` if you want to use it with `namedExport: true`. I recommend you to try it again.

Comment: I will give it a try, I did not try that, thanks!